# FsLex changed with latest PowerPack?

Tags: f#, fslex

I've been working on a compiler for a while but after changing to PowerPack 1.9.9.9 and the release version of VS2010 I'm no unable to compile the following line:

let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string text

I get the following two error:

"The value, constructor, namespace or type 'from_string' is not defined" pretty obviopus what it's trying to tell me but what's the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lexing.LexBuffer<_>.FromString ?

Comment: I'll avoid you the checkmark, it did help me on the way. It's fromBytes that the equivalent of the from_string from earlier version of the PowerPack

Answer (score 4):

My quick guess is that this function has been renamed to `fromString` (because, in general, functions with underscores such as `of_seq` are now written in `camelCase`).

Comment: pretty close but they introduce unicode parsing/lexing with the latest version of the powerpack so fromString is for unicode and the equivalent is fromBytes but thanks (and I don't need unicode parsing)